# Swift use UIButton method for UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton

Here is my code, I try to go through all programmatically created buttons, and if I found the needed one, then change its background, but I don't know how to do it, because subview is the instance of UIView, not UIButton.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        for subview in self.view.subviews {
            if subview is UIButton{
                if Int(currentDayKey) == subview.tag{
                    do {
                        let fetchTodayRequest = StoryDays.fetchRequest()
                        fetchTodayRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", currentDayKey)
                        let currentDays = try context.fetch(fetchTodayRequest)
                        if currentDays[0].photo?.isEmpty != true{
                            subview.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(data: currentDays[0].photo!), for: .normal)
                        }
                    } catch {
                            print("")
                        }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `if subview is UIButton{` you can use `if let button = subview as? UIButton {`. Then reference `button` where needed.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if let button = subview as? UIButton, button.tag == Int(currentDayKey) {
            do {
                let fetchTodayRequest = StoryDays.fetchRequest()
                fetchTodayRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", currentDayKey)
                let currentDays = try context.fetch(fetchTodayRequest)
                if currentDays[0].photo?.isEmpty == false {
                    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(data: currentDays[0].photo!), for: .normal)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I've been thinking about "as", but didn't know where to put it. Thanks again!